# Size of a MyISAM table doubles after OPTIMIZE

Tags: mysql, performance, size

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `CalculatedResultsId` int NOT NULL,
  `Md5Hash` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `SectionData` json NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `foo`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `CalculatedResultsId` (`CalculatedResultsId`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Md5Hash` (`Md5Hash`);
```

which contains ~400k rows and is ~800MB big. This is the output from PMA:

[image]

Then I delete 2'454 rows [< 0.6%], which produces an overhead of around 5MB which is also *documented* in PMA:

[image]

Running `OPTIMIZE Table` suddenly doubles the size of this table. I checked the real size of the table file in the directory and this is correct. It really doubled!

[image]

**My question:**

Why, what is going on? What happened, what is the reason, that the table size doubled?

The only way I found how to reduce the size of the table as it was before is to create a new table and re-fill it. Another very strange fact:

Running this command in order to get the copy of the big table `CREATE TABLE foo_new AS SELECT * FROM foo;` runs for 27! minutes for these 400k rows.

[image]

Creating an empty table and then copying with `INSERT INTO foo_new SELECT * FROM foo` needs 24! seconds.

Why such a difference? I don't know, but somehow it looks to me like a very serious design problem in MySQL, or a bug.

MySQL 8.0.20 running on SLES 15.1

Comment: your row size just doubled and a bit, maybe it is a bug. i can't see why it should be so. I hope you made a backup before doing such things

Comment: @nbk Don't worry, The servers are VM on a Citrix host with enough backups and snapshots. That far nothing happened, but it's strange. See my answer. It's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 4 month ago [filed bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98511) and it is fixed in MySQL 8.0.22.

Comment: Sounds like a nudge to get away from MyISAM.  I wonder if the Data Dictionary is somehow involved in the regression.

Answer (score 0):

As for the slowness of the copying -- For each row it must check that there is not already a dup in each `UNIQUE` index.

Two workarounds (maybe):

- Increase `key_buffer_size`.
- Disable the indexes, do the load, then re-enable the indexes.  (Hopefully, this will cause it to do a file sort, which might be faster.)
- `CREATE` the table without the indexes, then `ADD` them.

Comment: With all request Rick, but I cannot agree. Why is the `INSERT SELECT *` version more or less 70 times faster? Here the index does as well exist

Comment: @PeterVARGA - Please time them again _and_ see what `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` says _during_ the loading.  I would like to know if one says "Rebuilding indexes" and the other says "Rebuilding using key_buffer" (or some such wording).  If they differ, then that will lead to the answer you seek.

Comment: I wanted to post the requested output and now, I cannot believe it myself, the copy using the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT *` version needs 14 seconds. I posted in the question the screenshot where it's visible. Of course, I haven't changed anything **AND** I didn't restart in the meantime the MySQL server. Very, very strange.

Comment: Not so strange.  That's caching.  Restart mysqld and it will be slow again.  When timing `SELECTs`, I recommend running them twice and trusting the second time.  (Your situation can't easily be rerun since it involves create table or insert.)  The caching is _probably_ on the `SELECT` side of the queries.

Comment: I forgot to mention I restarted the server as I thought exactly the same, e.q. it can't be caching. Now, it takes always these 14 seconds. To be 100% sure I restarted also the VM on which the MySQL server is running. Always these 14 seconds.

Comment: @PeterVARGA - 14s for both the CREATE...SELECT and the CREATE; INSERT..SELECT?  Is there still a 27 minute problem?

Comment: MyISAM uses table locks.  Any operation, even a `SELECT`, can prevent other operations on the table from starting.  Maybe a 27m select was running?  (Just a guess.)